# Why is the Magento Logout is not clearing the current session data?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I have an issue (I am using an older version of `IWD One Page Checkout`).

If you are logged in as `adam` and then `log out` and checkout as a guest.
The email it sends will have the previously logged in users data.

Also When you logout the header will still say:

```
Welcome, Adam Henry! (Not Adam Henry?) My Account Checkout Log In
```

I realised that the name is derived from this:

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getData()`

Which still persists the old session data.

Is this data supposed to be cleared on a logout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Persistent Shopping Cart** can cause this behaviour.
Try to disable it in the `magento admin backend`

`Admin -> System -> Customer -> Persistent Shopping Cart`

Comment: Just noticed that, in this case the `Clear Persistence on Log Out` change to `Yes` was good enough

Comment: @surfer190's suggestion was the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @surfer190 Even after its enable it does not work Magento 2.3 C.E x

Comment: do you know the way to force clear Quote after login on programming?